# Need to replace "$" to "_" with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I´ve got the following string from a .getAttribute():

```
ctl00$m$g_ff7ec6ac_ec2e_4402_aaaa_7fcce245ff1b$ctl03$_UserName
```

Let´s call it "String". Now I need to replace the $ to a _ . I tried:

```
String.replace(/\$/g, "\_");
```

... doesn´t work.

Second try:

```
String.replace(/$$/g, "\_");
```

... doesn´t work.

Third try:

```
String.replace(/\$$/g, "\_");
```

... doesn´t work.

So... Ca anyone help? Thanks for all effort!

EDIT: Need to get it work for IE8/9

The code at this time:

```
mailName = document.body.innerHTML.match(/ctl00\$.+EmailAddress/);
alert(mailName); // String is "ctl00$m$g_ff7ec6ac_ec2e_4402_aaaa_7fcce245ff1b$ctl03$_UserName"

mailName2 = mailName.replace(/\$/g, "_");
```

EDIT2:

... I´va got the answer one my own.

```
mailName = document.body.innerHTML.match(/ctl00\$.+EmailAddress/);
```

gives a string back but .replace() or .split() won´t work with it. To get ot work you need to do it like this

```
mailID = '"' + document.body.innerHTML.match(/ctl00\$.+EmailAddress/) + '"';
```

after that everything is fine. Don´t know why, but in IE8/9 this solution works great.

Comment: don't call it as `String`, `String` is a class.

Comment: `"hello$world".replace(/\$/g, "\_")` works fine for me, though you don't need the backslash before the underscore.

Comment: doesn´t work mean that the code stops at the point where the .replace() located

Comment: @FelixZeidler Can you give us more code ? Or a fiddle ?

Comment: If it's stopping then there'll be an error in the developer console. What is that error?

Comment: ... I´va got the answer one my own.

    mailName = document.body.innerHTML.match(/ctl00\$.+EmailAddress/);

gives a string back but .replace() or .split() won´t work with it. To get ot work you need to do it like this

    mailID = '"' + document.body.innerHTML.match(/ctl00\$.+EmailAddress/) + '"';

after that everything is fine. Don´t know why, but in IE8/9 this solution works great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/\$/g, "_");
```

No need to escape the second string.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

> Returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by
>   a replacement.  The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the
>   replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

Note also that replace doesn't change the original string. You need to get back the returned value.

And, regarding your edit, note that the [match function of Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7df7sf4x(v=vs.94).aspx) seems to return an array even without the `g` modifier :

> If the match method does not find a match, it returns null. If it
>   finds a match, match returns an array, and the properties of the
>   global RegExp object are updated to reflect the results of the match.

You can do

```
var str = ''+ document.body.innerHTML.match(/ctl00\$.+EmailAddress/);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/jfyyY/)

Comment: This is true, though putting a backslash before the underscore doesn't really hurt anything.

Comment: Sorry... Doens´t work. It may work for FF but I need to get it work for IE8/9

Comment: It seems to me the I can´t use the string for anything else... It doesn´t matter whether I wan´t to replace a char or split the string. The code ends up in the line of code where I want to work with it :-/ If I make a comment out of the replace-line everything is fine, but I need to replace this :-/

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demonstrating your problem ? Or try to see what is different from my fiddle in your program ?

Comment: "If the regular expression includes the g flag, the method returns an Array containing all matches. If there were no matches, the method returns null." that´s true... But in my code is no g flag.

Comment: Thanks ;-) Solution is working and makes my code a bit more elegant without .slice()